Access RabbitMQ message headers from MassTransit consumer
Is there a way to get the message headers from RabbitMQ (different than the headers set through MassTransit)?
My use case is, I'm trying to read the timestamp added by RabbitMQ, timestamp_in_ms (previously generated by RabbitMQ plugin, now native via configuration).
I've checked the docs and debugged, but couldn't find any RabbitMQ header key in what I receive.
I'm aware MassTransit adds its own "SentTime" on the message envelope, but I believe this is different than the timestamp as filled in by RabbitMQ itself (with server local time of the broker).

Within a consumer, you can use:
var ts = context.ReceiveContext.GetSentTime();
if(ts.HasValue)
{
    // do something with it?
}

That should get the Timestamp from the BasicProperties if present.
Otherwise you can try using context.ReceiveContext.TransportHeaders.

GetSentTime for some reason seemed to return an incorrect datetime, quite likely I'm doing something wrong, but context.ReceiveContext.TransportHeaders solves my use case entirely, as it allows me to access timestamp_in_ms. Thanks so much Chris!

GetSentTime() uses the Timestamp on BasicProperties, if present. I never saw the header you mentioned in any of my tests, so it must be something I don't have enabled.

This is the old plugin that enabled the timestamp to be added.  As of 3.12, the same functionality is now native but you have to activate it via rabbitmq.conf (or at least that's the only way I know).
